# Render issue java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner

Tags: java, android, rendering, render

[image]i have recently faced this render problem which avoid preview of xml file in android studio!

full error message is

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Cleaner   at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation_Original(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:130)   at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry_Delegate.java:66)   at libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:119)   at android.os.Binder.<init>(Binder.java:404)   at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub.<init>(IInputMethodClient.java:18)   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$1.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.<init>(InputMethodManager.java:606)   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager_Delegate.getInstance(InputMethodManager_Delegate.java:43)   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.getInstance(InputMethodManager.java:681)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.setUp(RenderAction.java:249)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderAction.init(RenderAction.java:137)
```

i found same question on stackoverflow but that was about IntelliJ IDEA .
and one question about android studio which had no answers!

i was using android studio 3.6 when this happened! then i updated to 3.6.1 and problem still exists!

then i downgraded to 3.5.3 and problem solved but this morning i woke up and see the same problem in 3.5.3 version too!

any help would be appreciatated.thanks

Comment: try invalidating cache and restarting the android studio

Comment: dear Phantômaxx,that question also never answered well...it says that is a known bug which will be fixed.but still no fix in 7 months

Comment: dear Jamshaid...that not helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why and how but for those who faced same issue! i fixed that by download and using android studio 4.0 beta 2